# How can I read (and write) Mifare DesFire Cards with Android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, mifare

I'm trying to read and write with an android app an mifare desfire card (classic works already) but don't know how it works :). I know it has something to do with transceive(byte[]) which is responsible for communicating through raw bytes but how does it work in detail? Can you give me some Code-snippets?

Thanks a lot and best regards.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11524507/27190?

Comment: See linked answer above. Basically, you need to get protocol documentation from NXP and implement it in your app on top of `transceive()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I already read the entry mentioned above. I thought there is already some work done jet but it seems so, that I have to implement the protocol by my one. If someone did this job already I'm very interested in the solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi, me again :). If I understand you right with the transceive() method I'll get the raw-bytes and the protocol is used to now which bytes are responsible for what? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXP roll out an SDK to handle the communication with for example the Mifare DESFire EV1 cards: https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/taplinx/

Comment: Hi, i read that about their SDK but saw about the LITE version and the advanced version which is 1 euro per app distributed. Wondering if i can use the LITE version to write to the password to the 3DES password area?? I am pretty new to this,still trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the late response...still working on that?

Answer (score -1):

It is rather complicated than that, because all communication is ciphered and could also be with CMAC.
I've found a high level SDK than does all the job so you don't have to deal with transceive and all that, private message me if you are interested..

Comment: I can't send you an private message or didn't find the possibility in your profile. Can you please send me further informations about the sdk? THANKS!

Comment: @Jules I have a few issue with new SDK.
    credit
    debit
    getValue

Any idea?

Comment: @aung what kind of problem do you have exactly?

Comment: @Jules I understand SDK pretty well now and already code a few lines and it work. I will test more in a couple of weeks times and will post if I hit the bumpy road again. Many Thanks