# Change Listen A Parameters in HCE

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I'm using Moto XT-1095. The default parameters are:

```
ATQA: 0x0004
Historical Bytes: N/A
```

To be compatible with an existing reader, I have to set the parameters as:

```
ATQA: 0x0008
Historical Bytes: 0x4858
```

Currently, I do this by modifying `nfa_dm_discover.c` to set `NFC_PMID_LA_BIT_FRAME_SDD` to `0x08` and to add `NCI_PARAM_ID_LA_HIST_BY` field.

Is it possible to change these parameters without modifying the ROM or rooting?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Android NFC/HCE API does not allow you to set these parameters. Thus, the only options are to create your customized ROM that provides a means to set these parameters or to [modify libnfc-brcm.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720342/2425802) on a rooted device.