# Can I change the UID of NFC tags

Tags: tags, customization, nfc, uniqueidentifier, serial-number

In my Android application am using NFC Type 1 tags. From the NFC tag I am reading card data and I also want to get the unique identifier (UID). Am able to read both `data` and `UID` but now I want to change the UID of my NFC tag.

I tried with various applications like *NFC Tools*, *NFC Tag Writer* but there is no way to change the UID.

I searched but only found that some [mifare](/questions/tagged/mifare) type of cards come with writable UID. So does anyone know whether the UID of NFC Type 1 tags is editable or not?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to modify these UIDs?

Comment: yes, actually i have added some authentication, for that i need some specific values only.

Comment: Hey man look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409934/editing-functionality-of-host-card-emulation-in-android And it should work i am trying to do it on a non-rooted device maybe if i remember i will let you know if i succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

No, the UID of genuine Type 1 tags (from Broadcom or, formerly, Innovision) cannot be changed. That UID is a serial number that is permanently burned-in into read-only memory during the manufacturing process.

I'm not sure for Type 1 tags, but there are certainly other NFC-A tags available (typically from Chinese suppliers) that behave similar to NXP MIFARE products and permit changing the UID using special commands.

Note that it's a really bad idea to use the UID/anti-collision identifier (or any other freely readable data) of NFC/RFID tags for authentication purposes since that information can easily be cloned. See also:

- [Serials on NFC Tags - truly unique? cloneable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21700718/2425802)
- [How do NFC tags prevent copying?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/63483/47234)