# Android NFC Card Emulation try to emulate a card

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, contactless-smartcard, hce

I'm trying to use NFC to emulate a card.

What I expect is that when I pass the phone on an NFC reader the reader reads the data (this data then I would modify in the future).

- I'm using this sample project: [This sample project](https://developer.android.com/samples/CardEmulation/index.html)
- I'm using a Nexus 5.
- I'm using an ACS ACR128 reader: [This reader](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/driver/36/acr128u-dual-interface-smart-card-reader/)

Passing the phone on the reader, for what I understand, the entry point should be in the Java class `CardService.java`. But the method `processCommandApdu` is never called (I have tried to insert a breakpoint there and even a toast, but that code is never called).

So at the moment the main thing that I can not understand is: Did I do something wrong? This thing can be done?

Comment: What did you do on the reader side to interact with the emulated card?

Comment: About the reader I have just installed the drivers in order to make it works

Comment: So why would you expect the reader to read anything if you don't program it to do so?

Comment: Because i think that with the sample project "CardEmulation" be able to emulate the device as if it were a card. At least i think it should call the method

Comment: That's correct. That sample project will make the phone emulate a contactless smartcard. But you will also need some software that uses the reader hardware to actually *read* that emulated card. Without such software the reader won't know how to interact with the card and, consequently, the CardEmulator application won't be invoked.

Comment: I use a driver of the reader acs acr128.
I tested it with NFC cards and works fine.
I also use a GUI program called "cardpeek" and this is a screenshot of what the reader reads hovering on the reader with the app open: 
[screen reader of the phone](http://oi67.tinypic.com/2ywhddz.jpg)

In this case I run atr read but my aim is to emulate a calypso card.
(I think first I have to understand the basic reading)
(another information: the reader reads perfectly a calypso card)

Comment: So you **do** use some reader software after all. Android HCE starts at the ISO 8716-4 (APDUs, smartcard application) layer. You won't be able to control parameters used for anti-collision and protocol activation, such as the UID or the ATS (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20068329/2425802). In order to interact with cardpeek, you would need to know what application IDs (AIDs/DF names) it tries to select. Once you know that information, you can register the CardEmulation samle application for those AIDs. Only then, Android will forward communication to your HCE application.

Comment: Ok, how do I figure out which select does Cardpeek?
I tried to see in the command log running when reading a Calypso card but I did not understand. So if I understand correctly, I have to figure out which does the reader select (id) and then add it to the app file called "aid_list.xml"? (So the reader call is taking charge from the app)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: any suggestions to give the command of cardpeek that makes the select? (in lua language)

Comment: Ok I understand and it works. But I have a doubt, you can change APDU HEADER in an Android phone?

Comment: Why would you want to change the APDU header on the Android side? That's part of the command that you **receive** from the reader. I don't see the point in changing that at the receiver.

Comment: I need change header on the device because i need to emulate a Calypso card. if you use the header default the device detects the select. But if I do a select like a Calypso Card then it does not detect anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the method `processCommandApdu()` to be called for incoming APDU commands, the reader needs to select your application first. Selection is done using the SELECT (by AID / DF name) command according to ISO/IEC 8716-4:

```
00 A4 04 00  <Lc>  <AID>  00
```

Where `<Lc>` is the length of `<AID>` and `<AID>` is the application identifier registered for your app.

The ISO/IEC 8716-4 application structure (i.e. application selection through a SELECT (by AID) command) is the **only way** Android allows to start interaction with an app over HCE. Consequently, it's **not** possible to emulate cards (card applications) that use different mechanisms. (At least not without modifying the Android system itself; e.g. though a customized ROM or through Xposed.)

AIDs for the CardEmulation sample app are registered through a file named `res/xml/aid_list.xml` in the example project. In this file you register AID groups, which in turn contain AID filter entries:

```
<aid-group android:description="@string/card_title" android:category="other">
    <aid-filter android:name="F222222222"/>
</aid-group>
```

Therefore, the default AID that is registered in the example app is `F222222222`. Hence, you can use the following SELECT (byte AID) command to select the application:

```
00 A4 04 00  05  F2 22 22 22 22  00
```