# Clone an NFC Mifare Card (ISO 14443-3A) into my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, nfc, mifare

I have an NFC card from my city public transport, and I want to integrate in my Flutter app a feature that clones the data from the card and use the app instead of the card.

[Here](https://github.com/Iliescu-Dorin/CS-UBB) is a link to my open source app (it is still WIP). It is for the students in my faculty and I want to integrate this freature in this application.

I don't know how to get the data from the card in Flutter and send it when the phone is next to a NFC receiver (like those from buses).

Comment: As far as i know it's not possible to send Data with NFC on IOS. For Android this could technically work, but there is no library out there supporting this, only reading.

Comment: For Android: [Emulate Mifare card with Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20055497/2425802)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clone, I assume that you'd like to use your mobile device as the NFC card. What you can do here is copy the NFC tag's metadata using [flutter_nfc_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit) plugin then implement a NFC emulator using [nfc_emulator](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator) to have your device act as a NFC tag. Note that NFC emulator only supports Android at present.